# Proper way to subsubstring a char* without a memory leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, arduino

I'm developping a program for the arduino environement specificly the esp8266 and I need to substring a part of a received command  and convert it to a long

> Example:
>
> Received command: "HCHP 000527707 /"
>
> Output: 527707

I've created / inspired myself a substring function which works but eats a few bytes of heap each time I run which adds up to ~152bytes for a full frame that I've received.

```c
char *substr(char *src,int pos,int len) { 
  char *dest=NULL;                        
  if (len>0) {                         
    char* dest = (char*)calloc(len+1, 1);      
    if(NULL != dest) { 
      strncat(dest,src+pos,len);            
    }
  }                                       
  return dest; 
}
```

The only solution I could find after a lot of debugging is this one and **I know that this is bad and shouldn't be used like this** but it works and there isn't a leak.

```c
char *substr(char *src,int pos,int len) { 
  char test[len+1] ;
  String(src).substring(pos, pos+len).toCharArray(test,len+1)    ;   
  return test;    
}
```

Anyways can someone tell me what I did wrong on the first function.

And how can I put a `free()` as I'm returning `dest` I don't know whre to put it.

Comment: `strncat()` doesn't add a null terminator. You need to do that in your function.

Comment: Do you really need to return the substring, or can you just convert the substring to a long in one function?

Comment: You can free it in the caller after you convert it to a long.

Comment: "but it works". No it doesn't. Returning a local array invokes undefined behaviour. It may appear to work but can crash or produce any other unexpected behaviour at any time.

Comment: Bermar isn't that not needed since I use calloc which films with 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

> And how can I put a free() as I'm returning dest I don't know whre to put it.

Your (first version) function `substr` allocates memory and returns a pointer to it - so the only way you can free that memory is inside the caller of that `substr` function. Ie, whatever function which calls `substr` will need to remember to free the pointer returned by it.